# Kotlin Android Coroutines - suspend function doesn't seem to run in the background

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I feel like i'm missing some crucial part to my understanding to how this code below is working:

---

```
private fun retrieveAndStore() {
        launch(UI) {
            val service = retrofit.create(AWSService::class.java)
            val response = service.retrieveData().await()
            store(data = response)
        }
    }

    private suspend fun store(data: JsonData) {
        val db = Room.databaseBuilder(applicationContext, AppDatabase::class.java, "app-db").build()
        db.appDao().insert(storyData)
    }
```

This is the error i get when run:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.
```

I don't understand why the network code via retrofit works but the store function fails.  I'm hoping someone can tell me what's going on?

Interestingly if i wrap db call with async {}.await it works, does that mean coroutines can only call other coroutines?

Comment: `launch(UI)` runs on the UI thread, which is the foreground.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Coroutines aren't about running in either foreground or background. They are about the ability to get suspended, just like a native thread gets suspended by the OS, but on the level where you are in control of that behavior.

When you say `launch(Dispatchers.Main) { some code }`, you tell Kotlin to submit "some code" as a task to the GUI event loop. It will run on the GUI thread until explicitly suspended; the only difference is that it won't run right away so the next line of code below the `launch(Dispatchers.Main)` block will run before it.

The magic part comes around when your "some code" encounters a `suspendCoroutine` call: this is where its execution stops and you get a continuation object inside the block you pass to `suspendCoroutine`. You can do with that object whatever you want, typically store it somewhere and then resume it later on.

Often you don't see the `suspendCoroutine` call because it's inside the implementation of some `suspend fun` you're calling, but you can freely implement your own.

One such library function is `withContext` and it's the one you need to solve your problem. It creates another coroutine with the block you pass it, submits that coroutine to some other context you specify (a useful example is `Dispatchers.Default`) and then suspends the current coroutine until that other one completes. This is exactly what you need to turn a blocking call into a suspendable function.

In your case, it would look like this:

```
private suspend fun store(data: JsonData) = withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
    val db = Room.databaseBuilder(applicationContext, AppDatabase::class.java, "app-db").build()
    db.appDao().insert(storyData)
}
```